# View disappears when I set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO`

Tags: ios, cocoa

I don't know if this is a bug or I'm doing something wrong:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    UIWindow *window = [self window];

    UIViewController *main = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UIViewController *vc1 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UIViewController *vc2 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

    [main addChildViewController:vc1];
    [main addChildViewController:vc2];

    UIView *mainView = [main view];
    UIView *v1 = [vc1 view];
    UIView *v2 = [vc2 view];

    [v1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [v2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [v1 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [v2 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [v1 setClipsToBounds:YES];
    [v2 setClipsToBounds:YES];

    [mainView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
    [mainView addSubview:v1];
    [mainView addSubview:v2];

    NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:v1
        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
        toItem:mainView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0
        constant:0.0];
    [mainView addConstraint:constraint];

    constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:v1
        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
        toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0
        constant:240.0];
    [mainView addConstraint:constraint];

    constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:v2
        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
        toItem:v1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];
    [mainView addConstraint:constraint];

    [window setRootViewController:main];
    [window setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    [main release];
    [vc1 release];
    [vc2 release];

    return YES;
}
```

`v1` and `v2` appears nowhere when I launch the app.

If I comment out:

```
[v1 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[v2 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
```

Cocoa wouldn't be able to satisfy my constraints because of the autoresizing mask that was translated into constraints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have any horizontal constraints and the height constraint for v2 is missing. Using the visual format language you need something like `|-[v1]-|`, `|-[v2]-|` and `V:[v2]-|`

```
NSArray *constraints;

constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-[v1]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"v1": v1}];
[mainView addConstraints:constraints];
```

Comment: Wow, that did it. I had the idea that I was missing some kind of constraint, I added a height constraint to `v2` as well, but that didn't work so I just gave up. Thanks!